# Python get mouse click on pure text program no graphics interface

Tags: python, events, click, mouse

I have a Python while loop that reads, interprets and prints out a long text list.
I wish to intervene in the loop (hold it or do something else) by a mouse click, but I do not need or want a graphic interface (don't care where the mouse points at).
All mouse clicks that I have found are based on a GUI which I do not need.
Any easy way of doing it?
Thanks

Comment: what is holding your text? a browser?

Comment: The text is being parsed, its parsing results is sent to an I2C device where it is displayed and saved back into a file by the Python device (RaspberryPi3).